# how do I swap both axes in the current plot in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a function like this.

```
u = (1 / 4 Sin[t] (1 - r^2)) ;
Plot[u,{r,0,1}]
```

The above command will plot "U" on Y-axis and "r" on X-axis, But I want it in the reverse direction. "U" on X-axis and "r" on Y-axis.

How to do this, I'm new to Mathematica.

Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this Question using the ParametricPlot command

```
ParametricPlot[{(1 - r^2) /. r -> Abs[r], r}, {r, -Pi, Pi}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tabulate the results using `Table` and reverse each data point

```
Clear[t, u]

u[r_] := (1/4 Sin[t] (1 - r^2));
t = 1.57;

ru = ListLinePlot[table = Table[{r, u[r]}, {r, 0, 1, 0.01}],
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {r, u}];
ur = ListLinePlot[Reverse /@ table,
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {u, r}];
GraphicsRow[{ru, ur}]
```

[image]

Or you can generate an inverse function to use in `Plot`

```
Clear[t, u]

u[r_] := (1/4 Sin[t] (1 - r^2));
t = 1.57;

plotru = Plot[u[r], {r, 0, 1},
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {r, u}];
Clear[t, u]
v = Quiet[InverseFunction[(1/4 Sin[t] (1 - #^2)) &]];
t = 1.57;
plotur = Plot[-v[x], {x, 0, 0.25},
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 200, AxesLabel -> {u, r}];
GraphicsRow[{plotru, plotur}]
```

[image]